# Is there a way to hardcode the site logo image path in the masterpage?

Tags: master-page, branding, site-logo

We are have a webapplication and have deployed a feature stapler that assigns the master page to each newly created site [(reference).](http://frederik.se/how-to-brand-sharepoint-2013-team-sites-using-feature-stapling-in-vs/)

I want to know a way in which we can hardcode the image path into the masterpage so that the image (site logo) gets applied to all sites along with the masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

Put a [SiteLogoImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.sitelogoimage.aspx) control in your master page and hardcode its [LogoImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.sitelogoimage.logoimageurl.aspx) property.

The hardcoded logo can be overridden on an individual site by going to Site Settings > Title, Description, and Icon.

```
<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage ID="logoImage" runat="server" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:

Along with default master and custom master we can set the site logo as well.

```
web.MasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/testmaster.master";
web.CustomMasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/testmaster.master";
web.SiteLogoUrl = webAppRelativePath + "Style%20Library/HD_Internal_Images/testmaster.png";
```

Comment: Much better than hardcoding it :)