# changing logo in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, branding

I am trying to change my company logo in SharePoint 2010, can you tell me how I can change it and when I change does it changes on all of its sub sites. Please help I am stuck on doing that.
Currently, we are having an old logo and it needs to be replaced with new one. I went to the main site and under look and feel. I see "master page" but not sure where to change that
This was done by someone else and now I need to change to a new logo. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the powershell then try this one

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$siteurl = "https://test.sp2010.dev"
$sitelogo = "/Style Library/My Project/Images/logo.png"
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
 $web.SiteLogoUrl = $sitelogo
 $web.Update()
 $web.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()
```

http://www.broculos.net/2013/10/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-site-logo.html

Comment: i do have access to ppwershell. Can I just copy this and paste it. How do i add my changes from where the image is selected?

Comment: you have to upload the logo on site first.. then change the site collection url n logo patrh.

Comment: okay, I have added the images at site collection images. do you mean just change the second and third line as per my needs and remaining can be the same

Comment: Yes sir, then this script will change logo to site collection along with all subsite

Comment: Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$siteurl = "http://intranet/SitePages/Intranet.aspx"
$sitelogo = "/SiteCollectionImages/newlogo.jpg"
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
 $web.SiteLogoUrl = $sitelogo
 $web.Update()
 $web.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()

Comment: can you check for the code and say if this is correct

Comment: code looks ok, i am thinking you mask the url of the site collection....it should be like http://sitecollectionurl

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: u mention this "intranet/SitePages/Intranet.aspx" in your code but site collection url should be like this http://sitecollectionurl

Comment: you mean   $siteurl = "http://intranet/SitePages/Intranet.aspx"

Comment: yes that should be correct url

Comment: Just to clarify, can i just change the image in sharepoint designer where the image is located. eg: my images is stored in styles/images/logo.gif   I can also just replace the new logo with the same name and that image will replace and change the logo everywhere. am i right? please advise

Comment: I think, yes it will change. if you simply change the replace the image with same name and type

Comment: thank you. while searching for its location i found that so wanted to clarify before changing. I will be changing the logo once we get approval. And will update if that works. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: i would highly recommend you to do it in test site first. QA or create another test site collection. Dont do in production without testing.

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot create test site collection. I can test in a single sharepoint site and clarify right?

Comment: its risky, You should have a test farm...may be create on your pc( as VM) to test the things 1st...EVEN it we know it works but still as a recommended approach / best practice...test 1st.

Comment: is there any other option you think? I dont have access to all those things from my end.

Comment: Do you have Laptop then create VM on there and isntall the SharePoint or try this web site as they give free trail sharepoint hosting http://sharepointhoster.com/free-sharepoint-2013-hosting

Answer (score 0):

Under site settings -> Under Look and Feel click Title, Description, and Logo.

Comment: does this changes in all the subsites and all the templates?

Comment: @MohammedEliyasAhmed it changes the logo of only the current site. If you want to apply across sites then you need to use PowerShell or edit master page and put your logo there.

Comment: Do you mean going into look and feel and under there we have "master page" you want that to be edited right?

Comment: But I am confused on how to change that

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94518/is-there-a-way-to-hardcode-the-site-logo-image-path-in-the-masterpage